# Eclipse & Tomcat ERROR 500

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have created a form for registration.
when I execute home.jsp and I try to do a registration I have this kind of error:
HTTP 500 STATUS

```
    Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    it.DBQuery.unique(DBQuery.java:59)
    it.Registration.doGet(Registration.java:43)
    it.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

---

this is my code of **Registration.java**

```
package java;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

        /**
         * Servlet implementation class Registration
         */
        @WebServlet({ "/registration" })
        public class Registration extends HttpServlet {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
             */
            public Registration() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             */
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DBQuery DB = new DBQuery();
                String login = request.getParameter("login");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
                String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");

                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("Login", login);
                session.setAttribute("FirstName", firstname);
                session.setAttribute("LastName", lastname);

                if(DB.unique(login)){
                    DB.register(login, password, firstname, lastname);
                    session.setAttribute("Logged-in", "true");
                    response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
                } else {
                    session.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", "Username already in use!");
                    response.sendRedirect("registration.jsp");
                }
            }

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             */
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                doGet(request, response);
            } }
```

---

DBQuery.java file:

```
package java;

    import java.sql.*;

    public class DBQuery {
        private String connectionURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SitoDB";
        private Connection connection = null;
        private PreparedStatement statement = null;
        private ResultSet rs = null;

        private String query = "select * from users where login=?";
        private String insert = "insert into users(login, firstname, lastname, password) values (?,?,?,?)";

        public DBQuery() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            // get a DB connection
            try{
                Class.forName("com.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "postgres", "12345");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() {
            try{
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }

        public boolean validate(String login, String password){
            boolean result = false;
            try{
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, login);
                rs = statement.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next() && password.equals(rs.getString("password")))
                    result = true;

                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public boolean unique(String login){
            boolean result = false;
            try{
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, login);
                rs = statement.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next())
                    result = false;
                else
                    result = true;

                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public void register(String login, String password, String firstname, String lastname){
            // should write data to DB table
            try{
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
                statement.setString(1, login);
                statement.setString(2, firstname);
                statement.setString(3, lastname);
                statement.setString(4, password);
                statement.executeUpdate();

                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }

        public String getFirstName(String login){
            String result="";
            try{
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, login);
                rs = statement.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) 
                    result = rs.getString("firstname");
                else
                    result = "";

                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public String getLastName(String login){
            String result="";
            try{
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, login);
                rs = statement.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) 
                    result = rs.getString("lastname");
                else
                    result = "";

                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

In my DB (created with PostgreSQL ) I have created a table USERS with login, password,firstname,lastname.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks you guys.

Comment: Anyone know how can I resolve?

Comment: Seems to be failing here 'statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);' Check that the connection is not null and the query is valid.

Comment: @Jaydee Thanks for the answer! How can I check this?

Comment: That depends on your development environment.

Comment: About my db? I have created a table users with login primary key, password, firstname, lastname.
Should I have to change the private String query = "select * from users where login=?"; ??

Comment: You need a way to step through code and examine the value of variables. Here's one http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ then you need to set it up for tomcat.

Comment: I used yet eclipse with tomcat. I don't understand what you suggest me to do

Comment: Check your stderr log. Seems the only way that `connection` should be `null` is if there is an exception thrown in your constructor. BTW don't bother re-inventing the wheel... use a connection-pool, such as one of the *two* that ship with Tomcat.

Comment: I really don't understand how can I do to solve this problem. :/

Comment: You can use eclipse to step through the code as it runs and examine the values of variables at each point. Teaching you how to do that is rather beyond the scope of what I'm willing to do, there are lots of tutorials on how to use Eclipse.